# JUnit Mockito @InjectMock an Autowired Sessionfactory Bean

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, autowired

I created a special applicationContext-test.xml to use it into my Test Classes.

**applicationContext-test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db/database.properties"/>
    <context:annotation-config />


    <!--        DATASOURCE                      -->
    <jdbc:embedded-database id="h2dataSource" type="H2">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:db/sql/create-db.sql" />
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:db/sql/insert-data.sql" />
    </jdbc:embedded-database>

    <!-- SESSION FACTORY -->
    <bean id="testSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="h2dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.medkhelifi.tutorials.todolist.models.entities"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> ${hibernate.dialect} </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- MUST have transaction manager, using aop and aspects  -->
    <bean id="testTransactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="testSessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="testTransactionManager" />
</beans>
```

Now I want to use my `testSessionFactory` as an Autowired Bean and inject it into my mocks.

**TodoDaoTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration (value = "classpath:/conf/applicationContext-test.xml")
public class TodoDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    @Mock
    SessionFactory testSessionFactory;

    @InjectMocks
    TodoDao todoDao;


    private boolean mockInitialized = false;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        if(!mockInitialized) {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
            mockInitialized = true;
        }    
    }

    @Test
    public void getTodosByUserIdShouldNotReturnNull(){
        User user = new User();
        assertNotNull(todoDao.getTodosByUserId(user.getId()));
    }
}
```

This is my TodoDao class
TodoDao.java

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class TodoDao implements ITodoDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationFacade authenticationFacade;

    @Override
    @PostFilter("filterObject.userByUserId == authenticationFacade.getAuthenticatedFacade()")
    public List<Todo> getTodosByUserId(int userId) {
        List todos;
        // this is line 30
        todos = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Todo where userId = ?").setParameter(0, userId).list(); // this is line 30
        return todos;
    }
}
```

When I execute my test method I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException 
at com.medkhelifi.tutorials.todolist.models.dao.TodoDao.getTodosByUserId(TodoDao.java:30)` at line 30 (as shown in TodoDao.java class)
I don't know if I missed something.

Comment: At what line does it throw NPE? Also can you post your `TodoDao` class implementation?

Comment: Ok I will add my TodoDao class Implementation.

Comment: Create the Dao yourself. You don't inject into mocks you record behavior. So your 'TodoDao` isn't a mock nor your session factory. So why make it more complex...

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the behavior for your `sessionFactory` mock. So when your method invokes `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` it returns null and this leads to `NullPointerException`.

Add below code in your test method `getTodosByUserIdShouldNotReturnNull` or your `setUp` method and also you will have to few more mock objects:

`when(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(sessionMock);`
`when(sessionMock.createQuery("from Todo where userId = ?")).thenReturn(queryMock);`

Comment: But Since my SessionFactory is already autowired from a real bean, it doesn't suppose to have its own session already created??

Comment: Why would you want your `sessionFactory` to use a real bean for unit testing? In unit testing, you test one specific class and mock every other dependent classes

Comment: I want to use a real sessionFactory Bean to test with H2 data (already created in my two sql script). Can I do it with only fictive mocked beans?

Comment: then it might be a problem with your sessionFactory bean, as you don't want to mock it.

Comment: Do you have an example or tutorial how to test with H2 datas? I googled without get any result

Comment: Check this - it may help. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-test-in-memory-database